# Finding Gradient and Hessian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question Reads :

\begin{align*}
\text{Let }\ u(x,y) &= \pi y^2e^x + y+\pi/2 \\
f(x,y) &= x-cos(u(x,y))
\end{align*}

Deduce the gradient and Hessian of $u(x,y)$

Deduce the gradient and Hessian of $f(0,0)$ at .

The $u(x)$ part is easy enough. I got gradient =

$$\nabla u=  
\left(\begin{matrix}\pi y^2e^x  \\
2\pi e^x y +1  \end{matrix}\right),\quad$$

Hessian :
$$  
\left(\begin{matrix}\pi y^2e^x & 2\pi e^x y \\
2\pi e^x y  & 2\pi e^x  \end{matrix}\right),\quad$$

...
So far so good, but here I'm not sure what the wisest option is.. I could probably find the derivatives of $x-\cos(\pi y^2e^x + y+\pi/2)$ using simple chain rule but I imagine the result will be a mess and the Hessian even worse. Is there a more clever way to do this?

Comment: Chain rule generalizes to higher dimensions, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#The_chain_rule_in_higher_dimensions

Comment: There is a more clever way, but it won't help you to avoid messy computations. In fact size of your problem is not so big to use multidimensional chain rule. Just compute this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Taylor expansion $-\cos (t+\pi/2)=\sin t=t+O(t^3)$ as $t\to 0$, setting $t=\pi y^2e^x+y$. The term $O(t^3)$ does not figure in the gradient or the Hessian, which depend only on terms up to the 2nd order. So, the gradient and Hessian of $f$ at $(0,0)$ are the same as for the function $x+\pi y^2 e^x+y$. Is this clever enough?

---

If not, then expand $e^x=1+O(x)$ and notice that $y^2O(x)$ can be ignored (3rd order term). The function reduces to $x+\pi y^2+y$, with the gradient $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and the Hessian $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&2\pi\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: "The subsequent development of calculus is a puzzling exception to the normal process of simplification in mathematics. Nowadays we have a much less elegant system, which downplays the use of infinite series and complicates the system of rules for differentiation and integration." -- John Stillwell, *Mathematics and Its History*